# Interfacing C and Python

Tags: python, c, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Calling C/C++ from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

I am looking to bridge a C++ and python code.

The interfaces needed by python code are :

> floatvect(): this one should return an empty float vector (basically a list)
>
> get_quant(input_list_2, self.m_state_num, self.m_qm_vector)

The corresponding C++ function is :

> int  equalwidth_quant(int target_num_state, FloatVec &raw_data, FloatVec &init_quant)

When my python code contacts get_quant, it should be able to call the corresponding C++ function and get the result. The result is basically stored in the last attribute of that C++ function.

Is there any specific libraries which I can use for achieving this?

Comment: I don't think this is a valid C function prototype.

Comment: `int equalwidth_quant(int target_num_state, FloatVec &raw_data, FloatVec &init_quant)` That's not a **C** function.

Comment: Yeah, that's a C++ prototype all the way.

Comment: I'm thinking he wants to call `equalwidth_quant` from inside of `get_quant`. Then again, it's entirely impossible to figure out what's really supposed to be going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `equalwidth_quant` as a [C-extension for Python](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html). Check out [Cython](http://cython.org/) or here's a simple [tutorial](http://starship.python.net/crew/arcege/extwriting/pyext.html).

Comment: Downvoters, do leave a courtesy comment.

Comment: I don't even think you deserve these down votes since the problem is actually in the question.